# echo If it is a different key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this `Array`:

```
$array = [
    0 => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    1 => ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    2 => ['g', 'h', 'i']
];
```

And I use the following `foreach loop` to `echo` them

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arrs) {
    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        echo $arr;
        echo 'X';
        //result:aXbXcXdXeXfXgXhXiX 
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to `echo 'X';` only if it is a new `$key` of `$array` to get the result of

```
result: abcXdefXghi
```

What I've tried was this

```
$new = false;
foreach ($array as $key => $arrs) {
    if ($new != $key) {
        $new = true;
    } else {
        $new = false;
    }
    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        echo $arr;
        if ($new) {
            echo 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

But the result was

```
result: abcdXeXfXghi
```

Comment: Practically speaking: `echo join('X', array_map('join', $array))`…

Comment: @deceze is this better or u_mulder's `true-if-else-false` to be used?

Comment: If this is literally what you want to do, I'd definitely go with my one-liner. But in practice you will probably want to do something more complicated, so it's impossible to say whether the same simplistic solution applies there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a flag and check it:

```
$first = true;
foreach ($array as $key => $arrs) {
    // Do not echo X before first array.
    if ($first) {
         $first = false;
    } else {
         echo 'X';
    }

    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        echo $arr;
    }
}
```

Or if your keys are numeric and 0-indexed - check `$key` value:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arrs) {
    if ($key > 0) {
         echo 'X';
    }

    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        echo $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to do `echo X` before last element of main array:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arrs) {
    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        echo $arr;
    }
    if ($key != count($array) - 1) {
        echo "X";
    }
}
//result: abcXdefXghi
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood, I think you're trying to do that :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arrs) {
    echo 'X';
    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        echo $arr;
    }
}
```

And if you don't want to show the X for the first new key, but only to the others :

```
    $first = true;
    foreach ($array as $key => $arrs) {
        if ($first) {
           $first = false;
        } else
        echo 'X';
        foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
            echo $arr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Because he said **What I want to do is to echo 'X'; only if it is a new $key of $array** and it contrasts with the result he asked for.

I was editing to add both options.